# Django multiple Foreign Key in one model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a Human Ressources project with 3 apps 'main website', 'CandidatePart', 'CompanyPart'.

I need suggestions to structure my models which are now the following:

CompanyPart:

```
class Company(models.Model):
       company_name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

       def __str__(self):
          return self.company_name

class Team(models.Model):
       company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       team_name = models.CharField(max_length = 500)

       def __str__(self):
           return self.team_name

class TeamMember(models.Model):
      team = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
      position = models.CharField(max_length=150,default='')

      def __str__(self):
          return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name + ' as ' + self.position

class HR_member(models.Model):
      company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

      def __str__(self):
      return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

CandidatePart:

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    HR = models.ForeignKey('CompanyPart.HR_member')
    company = models.ForeignKey('CompanyPart.company', default = '')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

I have two foreignkeys to access HR and company

So, how can I hide other Company details based on HR selection or Hide other HR details if any Company is selected.

Comment: With some database queries you should be able to do the same, Are you referring to the same coming in Admin Console ?

Comment: Hi Bipul, Thx for answering ;) I am not sure about what you mean 'referring to the same' I was referring to the Django admin panel

Comment: As in you asked for HR menu to be filled with filtered set once the company is selected in the admin console.

Answer (score 0):

You can do filtering at the admin console by adding code in admin.py of the respective module/app. For example if my project's name is xyz and i have an app named a,b and c and I want to do some filtering for b then in b/admin.py do something like this:

```
class xxxAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
//list_display = ['user', 'business_name'] => this line displays needed columns only, optional.

def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "user":
        kwargs["queryset"] = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)

    return super(xxxAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request,**kwargs)
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

For more details please refer to official documentaion [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)